# Proving $m^*(A \cup B) \leq m^*(A) + m^*(B)$

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, lebesgue-measure

Let $m^*(A) = \inf\{\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty {E_k}: \{E_k\} \text{ is a cover of } A\}$ where each $E_k$ is an interval (i.e. continuous open set)

**Prove:  $m^*(A \cup B) \leq m^*(A) + m^*(B)$**

---

**Preliminary proof:**

Let $\{I_k\}$ be a cover of $A$, then $m^*(A) = \inf\{ \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty |I_k|\}$, by the greatest lower bound property $m^*(A) + \epsilon \geq  \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty |I_k|$.

Similarly, let $\{J_k\}$ be a cover of $B$, then $m^*(B) = \inf\{ \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty |J_k|\}$, by the greatest lower bound property $m^*(B) + \epsilon \geq  \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty |J_k|$.

Then $m^*(A \cup B) \leq \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty |I_k \cup J_k| \leq \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty |I_k| + |J_k| \leq m^*(A) +m^*(B) + 2\epsilon $

where $\{I_k \cup J_k\}$ is a cover of $A \cup B$. Taking $\epsilon \to 0$ gives us desired result.

---

**Two problems:**

1. $m^*(A \cup B) = \inf\{\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty |I_k \cup J_k| \}$ is true? Recall the outer measure is cover by intervals, $I_k, J_k$ could be intervals but their union is not. i.e. $I_k = (1,2), J_k = (3, 4), I_k \cup J_k$ is not an interval...
2. Does $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty |I_k \cup J_k| \leq \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty |I_k| + |J_k|$ follow?

Comment: I don't see the point, in $m^*(A)$ every isolated points of $A$ can be discarded, and finally $m^*(A) = \mu(\bigcup_n [a_n,b_n]) = \sum_n (b_n-a_n)$ if they are disjoints. the problem arises when you consider $\lim_{k \to \infty} m^*(A_k)$ where $(A_k)$ is a sequence of sets $A_{k+1} \subseteq A_k$, for example the sequence of sets converging to the Cantor set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{A_k\}$ be an open cover of $A$, where $A_k$ are intervals, and $\{B_k\}$ is an open cover of $B$ where $B_k$ are intervals

Then $\{A_k\} \cup \{B_k\}$ is an open cover of $C = A\cup B$ by intervals. For simplicity, let's denote $C_{2k} = A_k$ and $C_{2k+1} = B_k$

But $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |C_k| = \sum_{k=1}^\infty |A_k| + \sum_{k=1}^\infty |B_k|$

As the $A_k$ and $B_k$ are independant, if we take the $\inf$, we get that

$$\inf \{ \sum_{k=1}^\infty |C_k| \} = \inf \{\sum_{k=1}^\infty |A_k| \} + \inf \{ \sum_{k=1}^\infty |B_k|\} = m^*(A) + m^*(B)$$

Now, remark that because the $\{C_k\}$ are a cover of $C$ by intervals, we have :

$$m^*(C) = \inf \{ \sum_{k=1}^\infty |E_k| , \{E_k\} \text{is a cover of} C \} \leq \inf \{ \sum_{k=1}^\infty |C_k|  , \{C_{k}\} \text{defined as above}\} $$

Hence the result

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, but my question remains (and maybe they are silly), how can we guarantee that $I \in \{A_k\} \cup \{B_k\}$ is an interval? And is it well known that $|A_k \cup B_K| = |A_k| + |B_k|$?

Comment: @Lookbehindyou : If $I \in \{A_k\} \cup \{B_k\}$, $I$ is either one of the $A_k$ or one of the $B_k$. And in my proof, I never considered $A_k \cup B_k$